# How to interact with ArcGIS data from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arcgis

I need to develop an ASP.NET MVC website that takes information from ArcGIS to show maps and other data. ArcGIS is currently running on a local PC so ArcGIS data would need to be exported to some format and uploaded to the server where the website runs so the ASP.NET MVC application takes it and do its job. After some research I found that there are (at least) 3 different ways to interact with ArcGIS: Javascript API, SDK for .NET and ArcObjects.

What would be a solution in order to take the ArcGIS exported data and work with it in ASP.NET? Is this a feasible or possible approach?

Comment: You already listed the options. What is the question? If you don't want the web site to call ArcGIS directly, there's no need to mention it - just write a utility in the language you want to export shapefiles, or use ArcGIS's built-in tools. If you want the web site to talk to ArcGIS, use the SDK. If you want the client's browser to do so, use the Javascript API

Comment: Can I use any of the listed options to work with ArcGIS data exported from a local PC and uploaded to the web server? The server will not have ArcGIS installed. The web server is not related to ArcGIS in any way,only data exported from the local PC will be available after upload it to the web server.

Comment: If the website does not talk to ArcGIS directly then, how can maps be drawn? Should I use another application/SDK/API?

Comment: ArcGIS is an application. The data formats could be various. Are you able to be more specific to the type of data formats that are being used?

Answer (score 1):

Every ooption of the listed by you, has an specific target:

1. **ArcGIS Javascript API**: it is designed to be used in webbrowsers, it shows geographic information using javascript, mainly it is intended to connect to ArcGIS Servers, as well as OGC Servers.
2. **ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET**: if you plan to develop a desktop application with WPF, this is your tool. Last versions of this SDK is also intended for Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) apps, Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps, native mobile apps in C# for Android, iOS
3. **ArcObjects**:The classic one, this SDK allows you to create WinForms applications with geographic information, also allows to create console applications for automate operations that involve geographic information or maps, it runs over .NET Framework.

Comment: Are all of the above options ArcGIS proprietary? If so, is a license required?

Comment: Yes, all of them are ESRI proprietary, you will need a Annual developer subscription, I think that you do not need to pay for the ArcGIS Javascript, just subscribe to the https://developers.arcgis.com/ program

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Server is a proper way to achieve what you are trying to do. I assume you don't have and don't intend to have one.

You can go with a poor man's GIS server implementation as you described above: put files on server, then write services which would parse those files and provide geometries in a format that your client side can understand. There are various libs for working with esri shapefiles so you could find what suits you.

If you plan to use ArcGIS Runtime to implement your own server I would advise to check licensing because usually it won't allow you as it is licensed per client deployment.

I would advise you to check what ArcGIS Online can offer. Upload you data to their cloud and consume it with your Javascript API. Look at the pricing and maybe free plan will suit your needs. https://developers.arcgis.com/pricing/